# maximum number of function recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

Suppose we have the function :

```
void foo(int x)
{
foo(x); 
}
```

on my machine (i7) will run approximately 260k times and generate segmentation fault. any idea why that happens ?

Comment: Nothing is unlimited on a computer, not even the stack size

Comment: 260k is pretty good. It will be *a lot* less in some other environments. Consider updating/refining the question: the title (how *much* recursion is allowed) and the question in the post (why a seg-fault occurs) diverge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you call a function, it require space on the runtime stack.  This is where variables local to that function have their memory allocated.  What's happening is that you're recursing so many times that you're running out of stack space -- a stack overflow.  (The name of this site!)

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

Comment: +1 .. but what is the *maximum* recursion allowed? What are some factors in this? Also, the example case *could* be TCO'ed under optimizations/inlining (by what/where?) ..

Comment: @pst, wouldn't his answer imply it is something like (amount of stack space)/(amount of space the function takes on the stack).  I imagine rounded down.  

Edit:  This is ignoring tail recursion, which could go on forever...

Comment: @DavidD I'm just trying to draw out a more detail response. I'm sort of curious if C/C++ have anything specific to say (guarantee, prohibit or declare UB) about this case.

Comment: @pst: I don't think the standard defines any sort of limit.  In fact, as far as I know, the standard does even specify that function calls have to have their local storage allocated *on a stack at all* -- it's just that the stack is *the paradigm* that everybody uses.

Comment: @sheu Ah, that's more like it - remember to update the answer.

Comment: @pst: that's "as far as I know", not "I know for sure" :-P

Comment: @sheu You're correct about the standard not requiring a stack.

Comment: so what is the best question in this case, in place of "maximum number of function recursion c++"

Answer (score 0):

Every time a function is called system stores its call in stack, in this case system will continue storing function calls until system stack becomes full. this state is called stack overflow.